# Sorting function in Pandas, returns messy data

Tags: python, sorting, pandas

I am trying to sort data in a CSV file using sort function in Pandas using the following code. I have 229 rows in original file. But the output of sorting is 245 rows, because some of the data in a field were printed in the next row and some of the rows do not have any value.

```
sample=pd.read_csv("sample.csv" , encoding='latin-1', skipinitialspace=True)
sample_sorted = sample.sort_values(by = ['rating'])
sample_sorted.to_csv("sample_sorted.csv")
```

I think, this problem happened because in some cells  data was entered by generating new lines. For example this is the content of a cell in original file. When I sort the original file, the second line was printed in a new row and 3 rows left empty between first and second line.

```
"Side effects are way to extreme. 



E-mail me if you have experianced the same things."
```

Any suggestion? Thanks !

Comment: can you post an output of: `print(sample.shape)`?

Comment: @MaxU, output of print (sample.shape) is (229, 10)

Comment: @Merlin, I thought it maybe some other character inside the file, such as arabic characters. yes the file has header.

Comment: @Mary, that's interesting. Can you upload your CSV file somewhere, so we can reproduce your issue?

Comment: @Maxu I can not, because the data are related to patients opinions.

Comment: @Maxu, I Edited the question with some information about the file. Would you please check it ?

Comment: @Merlin, please see the updated question.

Comment: What I would do is use csv "usecols" to parse in all other columns, then use "usecols to parse this column on its own...But make sure you check for "," it will throw off the row counts.

Comment: @Mary, I can't reproduce your issue using multiline comments - i'm getting the same # of rows. Try this: `sample.to_csv('sample2.csv')` - how many rows does it produce?

Comment: @ Maxu, it should be 230 rows but  I have 248 rows.

Comment: So, as i thought, it has nothing to do with sorting... It's difficult to help you without a __reproducible__ sample data set... :(

Comment: What you might want to do is open the file is excel and re-save as csv. See if that helps.  Second, convert the csv to json and read the json file... But those extra new lines  breaks will be a problem.   http://www.convertcsv.com/csv-to-json.htm

Comment: @ Merlin, because, the original file is 230

Comment: @Mary I understand the nature of the content is sensitive.  However, if this is an important problem to solve, it may be worth while to create a fake file that produces the same issue you are observing.  This way, you can share it with us.  The issue can probably be recreated with only a few rows.  This would help you get your answer quicker.

Comment: Another idea is to use "usecols" and place the problem column last,  this may force the new lines as blanks,but as @piRSquared suggests, we can help if we see some lines of code. good luck.

Comment: Share with us the first row of data of your csv, just replace each A-Z character by X and keep the rest (space, quotes, carriage return etc ) untouched

Comment: @Maxu, I created a sample file with few sample (just 3). Where do you want to upload the file?

Comment: @piRsquared, I created a sample file with few sample (just 3). Where do you want to upload the file?

Comment: @MaxU, this is the link for the file: http://www.filehosting.org/file/details/603630/exampledata%20for%20stackoverflow.csv

Comment: @MaxU, can you send specific link that I can upload it and it does not need your email ?

Comment: @Mary, http://www.filedropper.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to remove the newlines in your problem column.

```
sample=pd.read_csv("sample.csv" , encoding='latin-1', skipinitialspace=True)
sample["problem_column"] = (sample["problem_column"].
                            apply(lambda x: " ".join([word for word in x.split()])
                            )
```

and see if that helps at all. It's difficult to see why that's happening without a reproducible sample.